# Match phrase which may occur as initials or in an abbreviated format

Tags: regex, abbreviation

Is it possible with regex to match the initials of the words in a string? Example:

I want to match, say, `International Scrabble Association`, but it can come as `ISA`, `Intl. Scrabble Assoc.`, etc. Ideally they will all match `ISA`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether there's a way to do it natively and only in regular expressions, then no, there is no way to do that. You'll have to split your string and extract the initials (perhaps using a regex), then construct a new regex from that. So the solution depends on your implementation, of course, but here's an example in PHP:

```
<?php
    $str = "International Scrabble Assocation";
    preg_match_all('/\b(\w)\w*\b/i', $str, $matches);
    $regex = '/\b' . implode('\S*\s*', array_map(strtoupper, $matches[1])) . '\S*\b/';
    $tests = array('Intl. Scrabble Assoc.',
                   'Intl Scrabble Assoc',
                   'I.S.A',
                   'ISA',
                   'Intl. SA', 
                   'intl scrabble assoc',
                   'i.s.a.',
                   'isa',
                   'lisa',
                   'LISA',
                   'LI. S. A.');
    echo "The generated regex is $regex.\n\n";
    foreach ($tests as $test)
    {
        echo "Does '$test' match? " . (preg_match($regex, $test) ? 'Yes' : 'No') . ".\n";
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
The generated regex is /\bI\S*\s*S\S*\s*A\S*\b/.
Does 'Intl. Scrabble Assoc.' match? Yes.
Does 'Intl Scrabble Assoc' match? Yes.
Does 'I.S.A' match? Yes.
Does 'ISA' match? Yes.
Does 'Intl. SA' match? Yes.
Does 'intl scrabble assoc' match? No.
Does 'i.s.a.' match? No.
Does 'isa' match? No.
Does 'lisa' match? No.
Does 'LISA' match? No.
Does 'LI. S. A.' match? No.
```

[Here's the ideone](http://ideone.com/5anfU2) if you want to play around with it.

Comment: Yes, the question was "regex-only". Thanks for your answer

Comment: Actually, acheong, you inspired me: here is a way to do it: \bI\w{0,12}.? ?S\w{0,7}.? ?A  Of course, it will match Integrated Star Aloha, but in my context it's OK. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have no way to speculate what additional whitelisted string would be sensibly included in ".etc", so I can only build a pattern to validate the strings that you explicitly nominated.

The following pattern uses a series of alternations and optional subpatterns enclosed in non-capturing groups as well as word boundaries to prevent making mid-word/accidental matches.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0TYg6))

```
$tests = [
  'International Scrabble Association',
  'ISA',
  'Integrated Star Aloha',
  'Intl. Scrabble Assoc.',
];

$regex = <<<REGEX
    /
    \b
    I(?:nt(?:l\.|ernational)\s+)?
    S(?:crabble\s+)?
    A(?:\b|ssoc(?:\.|iation\b))
    /x
REGEX;

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    printf(
        "%36s : %s\n",
        $test,
        preg_match($regex, $test) ? '✅' : '❌'
    ); 
}
```

Output:

```
  International Scrabble Association : ✅
                                 ISA : ✅
               Integrated Star Aloha : ❌
               Intl. Scrabble Assoc. : ✅
```